# Unable to run silverlight application in private browser mode (incognito window)

Tags: c#, silverlight, google-chrome, incognito-mode

I am running my silverlight application in google chrome (incognito window). It keeps holding on silverlight loading image. I saw the exception in developer window console

```
Uncaught Error: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Operation not permitted.   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSecurityState.EnsureState()
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
   at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageSettings.get_ApplicationSettings()
   at SilverlightBlobApplication.MainPage..ctor()
   at SilverlightBlobApplication.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(UInt32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)
```

I found suggestion on a forum

"1. From within the Silverlight player, right click. 2. Click Silverlight. 3. In the window that appears, click the Application Storage tab. 4. In the next window, click the "'Enable application storage" checkbox. 5. Click the "Delete all' button. 6. Click Yes. 7. Click OK. 8. Click your browser's Refresh or Reload button to continue. "

but it does not solve my problem. I am getting the same error in internet explorer while using private browser mode. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you switch your browser into the private mode, it prevents Silverlight from using isolated storage. This is done by design in browsers and to my knowledge, you cannot do anything about it.

Comment: Hey Szymon, thanks for the suggestion. Please tell me the alternative that how can I persist some data at client end while using private browser mode.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure... Is storing it on the server an option?

Comment: Yeah very true. Best option is to store it on server. but I am using cookies here so that it will be easy to access my local data in private browser also.